# how to change the location of my flatbutton in flutter... (from most left to most right)

Tags: flutter, padding, flutter-layout

I have build a simple app to learn flutter. I want to move a flat button to the most right of the screen.

I cant seem to use padding property and I don't know why.

```
new FlatButton(
  onPressed: () => debugPrint("pressed"),
  child: new Text("DONATE",
    style: new TextStyle(
      fontSize: 16,
      color: Colors.green[400]
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
    FlatButton(
      onPressed: () => debugPrint("pressed"),
      child: new Text("DONATE",
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          color: Colors.green[400]
        )
      )
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out flutter layouts,[here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout.)

plus padding property is for inside the button to move the button manipulate the margin property.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Wrap your button in a container